# Very complex file copy process

Tags: linux, bash

I've got a complicated challange. I'm not very practical of linux and script but I need to solve a problem. I've got a file list.txt containing two column in the first there is the name of the objects and in the second there is variable. Now I want used this information to copy a specific files in specif directories. For example:

The working directory is this: `/nfs/BioGPSDB/pockets/MD/fixed/1/`

This is the file `/home/tommaso/Desktop/list.txt`:

```
121p1_004_______________  GCP
13gs1_001_______________  SAS
1am42_003_______________  GNP
1bmq1_003_______________  MNO
   ecc...
```

In the working directory show below there are a lot of directory and the name of some of this directories is correleted to the first 5 characters of name of the object present in the first column of the file "list.txt". For example: 1j4r3, 1t403, `121p1`, 1sdr4, `1bmq1` ecc...

In each of this directory there are a lot of files. I need, for each line of the file "list.txt" use the first column to select the direcoty, enter on this directory, select the file of interest and copy this in another direcory `(/home/tommaso/Desktop/pdb_files)`. The file of interest is called like the variable reported in the second column of the file "list.txt". Example:

```
directory: /nfs/BioGPSDB/pockets/MD/fixed/1/121p1
File of interest: "GCP_?.pdb" where "?" is one character (letter or number)
Final directory: /home/tommaso/Desktop/pdb_files
```

So in the end in the directory `/home/tommaso/Desktop/pdb_files` I must have all files like this:
`GCP_?.pdb, SAS_?.pdb, GNP_?.pdb, MNO_?.pdb ecc..`

So the script should read the `list.txt` file and for each directory named as the first 5 characters in each row of the first column it should copy the file named as the variable in the second column with extension `"_?.pdb"` in a final directory where all files will be present.

I hope to have been clear enough and I hope to find someone willing to help me because I don’t know where to start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that using something along these lines:

```bsh
cd /nfs/BioGPSDB/pockets/MD/fixed/1/
while IFS= read -r line
do
  echo cp -i -- "${line:0:5}/${line##* }"_?.pdb /home/tommaso/Desktop/pdb_files/
done < /home/tommaso/Desktop/list.txt
```

Remove the `echo` to actually copy your files when satisfied with the printed `cp` commands.

Assuming you only have *one* file matching the `${line##* }"_?.pdb` pattern in each directory, you can also name it in a way that matches the `_?.pdb` suffix shown in your question by changing the `cp` command line into:

```
cp -i -- "${line:0:5}/${line##* }"_?.pdb \
  "/home/tommaso/Desktop/pdb_files/${line##* }_?.pdb"
```

The `-i` option to `cp` instructs it to ask before overwriting files in the destination directory; it is not essential, based on your requirements, but it makes sense when files coming from distinct directories are copied/moved to a single directory.

This script assumes that each file name fragment is preceded by one or more spaces in `list.txt`. Replace the space in `${line##* }` with the character that immediately precedes the file name fragments if appropriate.

The `${line:0:5}` kind of expansion—which reads "substitute with the five-characters substring of the `line` variable that starts at index 0 (the first character)"—is supported in several shells (bash, ksh93, zsh, busybox ash, ...), but is not part of POSIX and notably not available in dash.